How to save Lexical Editor content from Yjs message in NestJS backend?
I'm working on a project using Lexical editor with Yjs for real-time collaboration, and my backend is built with NestJS. I’m trying to figure out how to get the content from the Lexical editor when using Yjs and send it to the backend for saving.
Is there a proper way to extract and save the content from the Yjs document or message in NestJS? If someone has experience with this or a similar setup, any code examples or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
I’m currently using Yjs to handle the collaboration with Lexical. I’ve set up Yjs on both the client and server side. So far, I’ve been able to sync the content between clients in real-time. However, I’m stuck on how to extract the editor content from Yjs and send it to my NestJS backend to save it in a database.

Have you had a look at the connection providers for Yjs? https://github.com/yjs/yjs?tab=readme-ov-file#connection-providers
